# What is difference between calling a blocking method with timeout and calling a non blocking method with timeout in java?

Tags: java, nio, blocking

Could someone please explain me what benefits we would get if we use non blocking method with timeout over the blocking method with timeout?

Context- Socket APIs

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as calling a non-blocking method with timeout, as there is nothing to time out.

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.